# Trying to use mysqli_real_escape_string with a OOP connection attribute, but its giving a warning

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am trying my hand at OOP PHP and this is my code for starting a database connection:

This is part of the lynda turorial. But in the tutorial, the tutor is using mysql functions, which are giving a deprecated message, so i tried converting all of this to mysqli, but the function mysqli_real_escape_string(), is giving a warning.

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in {file path} on line 38.

I don't know what is wrong, i have used this function before, in the procedural form, but here with the OOP, its not working properly. All help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase{

private $connection;

function __contruct(){
    $this->open_connection();
    }

public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

public function close_connection(){
    if(isset($this->connection)){
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
        unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

public function query($sql){
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    if(!$result){
        die("Database Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
        return $result;
    }

function mysql_prep($value){
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    if($magic_quotes_active){
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $value);
        return $value;
    }

 private function confirm_query($result_set){
    if(!$result_set){
        die("Database Query Failed: " . mysql_error());         
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();
?>
```

The config file is:

```
<?php
//Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? NULL : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER') ? NULL : define("DB_USER", "root");
defined('DB_PASS') ? NULL : define("DB_PASS", "");
defined('DB_NAME') ? NULL : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
?>
```

The file i am trying to run:

```
if(isset($database)){
echo "true";
} else{
    echo"false";
    }
echo "<br>";
echo $database->mysql_prep("It's Working?<br>");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in constructor name (so it is not called in your code when you create MySQLDatabase instance). It should be:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->open_connection();
}
```